# Auth::user() returns null in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I set up a custom guard and login controller
The login is fine but somehow it doesn't store the authenticated user

I've read this ["Auth::user() returns null in Laravel 5.2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160144/authuser-returns-null)
and this ["Auth::user() returns null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945769/authuser-return-null-in-laravel-5-8)

But I think my problem has nothing to do with the middleware

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\GuruAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::GURU_HOME;

    public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
    {
        return view('auth_guru.login');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('guru');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:guru')->except('logout');
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Akun;

class Guru extends Akun
{
    protected $table = 'guru';

    protected $guard = 'guru';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nip', 'nama', 'id_mapel',
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    public function mapel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mapel', 'id_mapel');
    }
}
```

config/auth.php:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'guru' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'guru',
        ],

        'ortu' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'ortu',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        'guru' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Guru::class,
        ],

        'ortu' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Ortu::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Route list:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name                 | Action                                                                 | Middleware      |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/dashboard        | admin.dashboard      | Closure                                                                | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/login            | admin.login          | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm           | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST     | admin/login            | admin.login.submit   | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth\LoginController@login                   | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                      | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api    |
|        | GET|HEAD | guru/dashboard         | guru.dashboard       | Closure                                                                | web,auth        |
|        | GET|HEAD | guru/login             | guru.login           | App\Http\Controllers\GuruAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm            | web,guest:guru  |
|        | POST     | guru/login             | guru.login.submit    | App\Http\Controllers\GuruAuth\LoginController@login                    | web,guest:guru  |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home                 | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth        |
|        | POST     | login                  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | murid                  | murid.index          | App\Http\Controllers\MuridController@index                             | web             |
|        | PUT      | murid/data-diri        | murid.update         | App\Http\Controllers\MuridController@update                            | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | murid/data-diri        | murid.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\MuridController@edit                              | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | murid/jadwal           | jadwal.index         | App\Http\Controllers\JadwalController@index                            | web             |
|        | POST     | murid/jadwal           | jadwal.store         | App\Http\Controllers\JadwalController@store                            | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | ortu/dashboard         | ortu.dashboard       | Closure                                                                | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | ortu/login             | ortu.login           | App\Http\Controllers\OrtuAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm            | web,guest:ortu  |
|        | POST     | ortu/login             | ortu.login.submit    | App\Http\Controllers\OrtuAuth\LoginController@login                    | web,guest:ortu  |
|        | GET|HEAD | ortu/register          | ortu.register        | App\Http\Controllers\OrtuAuth\RegisterController@showRegisterForm      | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | ortu/register          | ortu.register.submit | App\Http\Controllers\OrtuAuth\RegisterController@register              | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm       | password.confirm     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web,auth        |
|        | POST     | password/confirm       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web,auth        |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web             |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | register               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest       |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I've also tried adding this to the controller:

```
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        Auth::setUser($user);
    }
```

And when I tried to access the Auth::user() from a view, it returns null.

The view is directly called from the route/web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'guru'], function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'GuruAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('guru.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'GuruAuth\LoginController@login')->name('guru.login.submit');
    Route::get('/dashboard', function() {
        return view('guru.index');
    })->name('guru.dashboard');
});
```

EDIT:
Christophe Hubert, here is the screenshot after I override the function:
[image]
Actually it's the same as before

Comment: use like this `\Auth::guard('guru')->user();`

Comment: It still returns null

Comment: Replace `Auth::setUser($user);` with `Auth::guard('guru')->login($user);`

Comment: No, somehow it still returns a null @Digvijay. BTW is my post clear enough? If you need more source code then I'll post it

Comment: @ChristopheHubert can you please explain it? I don't really understand what you're saying. I tried to dd the Auth::user() in the authenticated method and it works, but when tried to access it from the view, it returns a null

Comment: Can you check in your Controller for this route: `RouteServiceProvider::GURU_HOME` that you can access the `Auth::guard('guru')->user();` ? Are you using `public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:guru');
}`

Comment: No, it still returns a null. That's the route of the view that i'm talking about. @ChristopheHubert

Comment: Can you share the function that calls that view?

Comment: I've posted the code @ChristopheHubert, it's called directly from the routes/web.php

Comment: Thanks, can you add the middleware `'auth:guru'` to this route?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I've added it. `})->name('guru.dashboard')->middleware('auth:guru');`. After the login, it just redirects me back to the default login route.

Comment: It's confusing, what was the result of `dd(Auth::guard('guru')->user());` in your `authenticated method`?

Comment: The result is `App\Guru` Model. It works when accessed from there. But not from anywhere else @ChristopheHubert

Comment: Can you try to override this function in your loginController: `protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }` And try to see what can go wrong inside?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert posted the screenshot

Comment: I can't really help more, I'm sorry - a tough one, maybe others can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know why that happens, and after finally giving up, I came up with a (not so clean) solution.
Now, instead of using multiple guards, I'm creating a relationship from the users table to the guru/admin table.

This is how I access it now `Auth::user()->guru` or `Auth::user()->admin`

I know this is not a good solution, but it's the fastest workaround I can found

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the config/auth.php file.
Maybe you have:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

If so replace in config/auth.php:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```